# Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) html5 desktop application

Tags: html, desktop-application, chromium-embedded

I am new to Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF). How can I create an HTML5 desktop application using CEF. I serached a lot. But still confused about developing the applicaion.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CEF application in different languages (c/c++ or C#, python or ...), what is your preference about that?

In case of C# you might want to try https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp, I used this one in the past and it worked really great!

There are also sample projects in the CEF svn found here: 
[CefClient](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/f229796a39e2db5a567752dbbc6ac0b53634da6f/tests/cefclient/?at=master) and [CefSimple](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/f229796a39e2db5a567752dbbc6ac0b53634da6f/tests/cefsimple/?at=master)

Together with this tutorial here: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial

In the past I used CefSharp and one time I changed the CefClient example (removed everything I didn't need) and rebuild it. Using CefSharp was a lot simpler than the CefClient.

Another possibility might be https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit but that isn't CEF so a bit offtopic

edit: 
For java there seem to be two CEF Wrappers

- [javachromiumembedded](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/)
- [javacef](https://github.com/wjywbs/javacef/)

See an example application here (code): [javacef](https://github.com/wjywbs/javacef/tree/master/windows/java/src/org/embedded/browser)

Comment: I am trying with Java.